# Insert query for multiple row where two columns data always remain same

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a query to insert multiple rows in which two-column data remains the same in each row. Is there any way in which we can write an optimized query rather than placing an insert statement again.

```
INSERT INTO public.shops(id, shop_id, tier_id)
 VALUES
(uuid_generate_v1(),'8011',(SELECT ID FROM PUBLIC.BETTING_TIER WHERE NAME='Daily Million 6 - North Ire')),

(uuid_generate_v1(),'8012',(SELECT ID FROM PUBLIC.BETTING_TIER WHERE NAME='Daily Million 6 - North Ire')),

(uuid_generate_v1(),'8013',(SELECT ID FROM PUBLIC.BETTING_TIER WHERE NAME='Daily Million 6 - North Ire')),

(uuid_generate_v1(),'8014',(SELECT ID FROM PUBLIC.BETTING_TIER WHERE NAME='Daily Million 6 - North Ire')),

(uuid_generate_v1(),'8015',(SELECT ID FROM PUBLIC.BETTING_TIER WHERE NAME='Daily Million 6 - North Ire')),
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I removed the `mysql` tag as `uuid_generate_v1()` indicates it's really Postgres

Comment: postgres @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

Rephrase as a pure `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.shops (id, shop_id, tier_id)
SELECT uuid_generate_v1(), t2.shop_id, t1.ID
FROM PUBLIC.BETTING_TIER t1
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT '8011' AS shop_id UNION ALL SELECT '8012' UNION ALL SELECT '8013'
 UNION ALL '8014' UNION ALL '8015') t2
WHERE t1.NAME = 'Daily Million 6 - North Ire';
```

Comment: Personally I would prefer the usage of VALUES() or an UNNEST() instead of the UNION ALL solution.

Comment: @Frank Frankly I would prefer to have these values in a bona fide table, ideally as the primary key of that table.  Then just do an insert join.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Tim's solution would be to use generate_series to create the shop ids, in case they're sequential:

```
INSERT INTO public.shops(id, shop_id, tier_id)
SELECT uuid_generate_v1(), i::text, b.id 
FROM generate_series(8011,8015,1) i
CROSS JOIN betting_tier b
WHERE b.name = 'Daily Million 6 - North Ire';
```